# Kernel panic - not syncing: BRKADRINT

Tags: boot, kernel, kernel-panic

One of the machines on the network started beeping continuously and was unresponsive locally as well over the network. We shut it down keeping power pressed. Upon reboot, the boot stopped with `Kernel panic - not syncing: BRKADRINT` the message previous was dealing with `aic79xx`. No `dmesg` log was produced, so this is just read from screen. After rebooting a few more times, it booted successfully.

Is there any way of finding out what caused it to beep/freeze? Apparently, the user of the computer saw the `kernel panic` message before. Not sure what could cause this, esp. since it's not consistent. Any ideas?

The machine is running `Debian Squeeze 2.6.32-5-amd64`.

Comment: If you're getting [POST beep codes](https://www.google.com/search?q=post+beep+codes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb), my suggestion is to start by looking up the beep codes for your particular hardware and ruling out any hardware failures.

Comment: There were no out of the ordinary beeps during `POST`. The beeping started when the system was up and running.

Comment: Have you got a RAID array? Where is the boot partition? Have you tried booting over PXE?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most obvious way is:

1. Run stress-tests (CPU, memory).
2. Update all firware (BIOS, adapters, controllers) and disable all unused features and devices in BIOS.
3. Upgrade kernel if it possible and enable [kernel dump on panic](https://superuser.com/questions/280767/how-can-i-enable-kernel-crash-dumps-in-debian)
4. If the panic returns, try to change components one-by-one.